# unable to open sqlite database from terminal

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data

I am using Core data in my application and I am trying to see the data I inserted from the terminal.

I am trying to open a sqlite database via terminal as per this [document](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html). However, when I try to open it, I am getting the following error. I am not quite sure, what's going on.

I tried removing all other previous versions of my app's database. I tried attaching the database as well using the following command

```
sqlite> attach "myapplication.sqlite" as db1;
```

None worked.

unable to open database "/Users/mymacbook/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Application/7E563301-F42C-48A5-8C8D-60C6B096DC92/Documents/myapplication.sqlite": unable to open database file

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it easier to just do something like this

```
$ sqlite3 myapplication.sqlite
```

at the command prompt

Assuming you're in the directory myapplication.sqlite resides.

If you don't want to do it that way

```
$ cd "/Users/mymacbook/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Application/7E563301-F42C-48A5-8C8D-60C6B096DC92/Documents/"
$ sqlite3
> attach "myapplication.sqlite" as db1;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried doing that, did not work though. One more thing is when I try to access /Users/mymacbook/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator through sqlitepro firefox plugin, I am not able to locate the part from /Library/Application Support/ ... Any thoughts on that ?

Comment: @codeinzone - Sounds like you need to figure out where the file is.

Comment: @codeinzone - (Keep in mind that, if you pass a full path, the embedded blank will foul up some accesses.)

Comment: could you please explain " the embedded blank will foul up some accesses"?

Comment: @codeinzone - I don't see any "red flags" in the above stuff, but many tools simply can't readily handle a path with a blank in it, at least not unless the blank is "escaped" with `\\`.  This problem occurs because parameters in a list are parsed apart at blanks.

Comment: `~/Library` (/Users/mymacbook/Library/) is a hidden directory by default in OS X version 10.7 and higher. I'm not sure if sqlitepro firefox plugin can override that or not. The following command should make it visible (I have not tried it) `chflags nohidden /Users/[username]/Library/`